# Kendo Upload not uploading files

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I'm experiencing an issue with Kendo UI and it's KendoUpload jquery plugin that seems to be server specific. I have multiple instances of Sitefinity throwing the same error, but I can't seem to determine what the root cause of the error is.  On the kendo upload success callback, I get an error that the response is undefined. Sure enough, as I track down the caller of this function - I get an empty array of files and it seems like this code is losing track of the file upload.

```
    function _kendoUploadSuccess(e) {
        if (!e.response[0].UploadResult) {
           alert(e.response[0].ErrorMessage);
             if (that._usedByMediaContentUploader) {
                that._fileRemovedHandler();
             }
```

Like I said, I think this is a configuration issue somewhere - but I can't seem to figure out what's causing it. Has anyone experienced an error like this or know how to address it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark because I don't know what your HTML looks like, but is your `<form>` tag equipped with the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute? If that's not present then the form data will submit but no files will be sent. It could be the cause of you receiving "undefined" in your handler.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen such error when I have a Related Documents and Files field on a dynamic module AND also I had removed the Title field (and use another field as unique identifier).

In this case Kendo upload fails due to a js script error in one of the Sitefinity's js files.

Is this your case?

Comment: Yeah, so what I think is happening is that our production server got locked down to where the app pool could not execute scripts and the error bubbles up through to the kendo upload script at the point I posted above. It's an error unique to that server, it happens on multiple sitefinity instances and those instances run fine in our dev envrionments.

Comment: With all that said, I really don't know where the error is occurring yet, but I suspect it was a server without the proper privileges. Case in point, I can't execute ps scripts.

Comment: Note that app pool does not execute scripts, they are executed by the browser. Are all js files downloading correctly? 
If so, check if the IIS is setup as described here:
http://docs.sitefinity.com/configure-the-iis-to-host-sitefinity-projects

Comment: the error I'm getting is in the admin screen and is when I try to upload an image to a library.

Comment: Ultimately the error I'm getting is a result of the ashx upload handler returning an empty array:

https://localhost/Telerik.Sitefinity.Html5UploadHandler.ashx

Comment: Do you upload in an Image library or in a Dynamic Module? You should provide more details

Comment: The error I'm getting is that I'm getting an empty response back from Telerik.Sitefinity.Html5UploadHandler.ashx as a result of attempting to upload an image to an image library through the sitefinity backend website (not a dynamic library). Clicking through content -> images -> default library -> upload image.

This happens with the quantum demo site, and other new installations on  the same production server. Those same builds work fine in other environments, so I'm left to believe this is an environmental issue but am not sure what yet. I can't find the source through just decompile.

Comment: The code of the Html5UploadHandler is in the Telerik.Sitefinity.dll assembly in the Telerik.Sitefinity.Modules.Libraries.Web namespace. You should have it registered in web.config as a handler (under <handlers> and under <httphandlers>

Comment: Thanks, I've started to look through the code to identify fault points (I should have referred to Web.config on this, duh). On initial inspection, the logic is wrapped in a try/catch block - so the fact that nothing returns is a bit mystifying.